# Jackson deserilizer not registering in webflux with kotlin coroutines

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jackson, spring-webflux

I have little problem with Jackson Deserializer.
When I add annotation in class:

```
        @NotNull
        @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonPointDeserializer::class)
        val pharmLocation: Point,
```

it deserialize correctly. But i don't want to add it everywhere in my code because I'm lazy, so I added in configuration:

```
@Bean
    fun jacksonCustomizer(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {
        return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer { builder: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder ->
            builder
                    .serializerByType(Point::class.java, JsonPointSerializer())
                    .deserializerByType(Point::class.java, JsonPointDeserializer())
        }

    }
```

And now funny point. Serializer is working correctly, but deserializer don't. I get error, json from request looks correctly `"pharmLocation":{"lat":20.0,"lng":20.0},` but on stack I see:

````
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.geo.Point]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.geo.Point` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBuffer$DefaultDataBufferInputStream); line: 1, column: 74] (through reference chain: *.backend.advert.request.NewAdvert["pharmLocation"])```
````

I think that using `awaitBodyOrNull` can be reason, but no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: The error message clearly says the problem, no? You don't have a default constructor. You can use `@JsonCreator` to overcome this problem

Comment: But deserializer works correctly when I add it using annotation. I'm able to deserialize field using annotation but not when I'm registering deserializer in bean.

Comment: Can you show the `Point` class please?

Comment: my point class is  `import org.springframework.data.geo.Point` and my deserializer code:
`class JsonPointDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<Point>() {
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): Point {
        val jsonNode = p.codec.readTree<TreeNode>(p)
        val x = jsonNode["lat"].toString().toDouble()
        val y = jsonNode["lng"].toString().toDouble()

        return Point(x, y)
    }
}`

Comment: Could you maybe also show the code that is deserializing that json? Or are these some spring internals?

Comment: I don't use any magic for deserializing, just spring boot starter

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am asking about. What *I* want from *you* is a [mre], because currently all I can do is just guess, and that doesn't help anyone, does it?